# Sorting Ruby Array of hashes with 2 date keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, ruby-hash

I have an array of hashes with 2 keys that have timestampvalues (YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM/SS) : *start_date* and *end_date*.

```
Array_initial = [
    { :started_at => 20201105143200, :ended_at => 20201105143900 },
    { :started_at => 20201105142900, :ended_at => 20201105143300 },
    { :started_at => 20201105142800, :ended_at => 20201105143000 },
]
```

I want to convert this array of hashes into an array of arrays but sorted by comparing both *started_at* and *ended_at* timestamps. So the result would be this:

```
Array_final = [
[:started_at, 20201105142800], 
[:started_at, 20201105142900], 
[:ended_at, 20201105143000], 
[:started_at, 20201105143200], 
[:ended_at, 20201105143300], 
[:ended_at, 20201105143900]
]
```

Can't figure out how to do that...

Answer (score 1):

First you want to change the structure from this:

```
a = [
  { :started_at => 20201105143200, :ended_at => 20201105143900 },
  { :started_at => 20201105142900, :ended_at => 20201105143300 },
  { :started_at => 20201105142800, :ended_at => 20201105143000 },
]
```

to something that matches the structure of your result:

```
[
  [key, timestamp],
  [key, timestamp],
  ...
]
```

so that you can sort it.

[`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [`Hash#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-to_a) will do that nicely:

```
a.flat_map(&:to_a)
# [
#   [:started_at, 20201105143200],
#   [:ended_at,   20201105143900],
#   [:started_at, 20201105142900],
#   [:ended_at,   20201105143300],
#   [:started_at, 20201105142800],
#   [:ended_at,   20201105143000]
# ]
```

Then [sort by](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) the [last](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-last) element and you're done:

```
a.flat_map(&:to_a).sort_by(&:last)
# [
#   [:started_at, 20201105142800],
#   [:started_at, 20201105142900],
#   [:ended_at,   20201105143000],
#   [:started_at, 20201105143200],
#   [:ended_at,   20201105143300],
#   [:ended_at,   20201105143900]
# ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick & perfect answer!